# Не обновляется youtube player

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

```
class Video {
    constructor(triggers, overlay, close) {
        this.btns = document.querySelectorAll(triggers);
        this.overlay = document.querySelector(overlay);
        this.close = this.overlay.querySelector(close);
    }

bindTriggers() {
    this.btns.forEach(btn => {
        btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
                if (document.querySelector('iframe#frame')) {
                    this.overlay.style.display = 'block';
                    if (this.path !== btn.getAttribute('data-url')) {
                        this.path = btn.getAttribute('data-url');
                        this.player.loadVideoById({videoId: this.path});
                    }
                } else {
                    this.path = btn.getAttribute('data-url');

                    this.createPlayer(this.path);
                }
        });
    });
}

bindCloseBtn() {
    this.close.addEventListener('click', () => {
        this.player.stopVideo();
    });
    this.overlay.addEventListener('click', () => {
        this.player.stopVideo();
    });
}

createPlayer(url) {
    this.player = new YT.Player('frame', {
        height: '100%',
        width: '100%',
        videoId: `${url}`
    });

    this.overlay.style.display = 'block';
}

init() {
    if (this.btns.length > 0) {
        const tag = document.createElement('script');

        tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
        const firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

        this.bindTriggers();
        this.bindCloseBtn();
    }
}
```

}

```
new Video('.promo__video__videoplayer_1 .promo__video__play', '.overlay', '.video__close').init();
new Video('.promo__video__videoplayer_2 .promo__video__play_2', '.overlay', '.video__close').init();
```

вообщем. есть на страничке 2 плеера, но почему-то при нажатии на триггер, показывается одно и то же видео, хотя data-url у кнопок стоят разные. кто-нибудь сталкивался с таким?

В консоле есть 2 ошибки:
`Cannot read property 'stopVideo' of undefined`,
`Cannot read property 'loadVideoById' of undefined`